# java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, return-value

Why do you think this function gives me always null??
Using another login program, which has the same code structure, it works greatly.
My DBURL is jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/database

```
    public String retrieveUserPassword(String userName, String password) {

    String query = "SELECT UserPassword FROM Access where UserName='"+userName+"'";
    String dbresult=null; //this might be the problem, but I must define it

    try {
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    }catch (ClassNotFoundException ex1) {

      System.out.println("Driver could not be loaded: " + ex1);
      Logger.getLogger(DatabaseModel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
    }
    try {

          //These are private variables declared at the top of the class 
          //and used by various functions   
          con = DriverManager.getConnection(DatabaseURL, userName, password);   
          st = con.createStatement(); 
          rs = st.executeQuery(query);

            if(rs.next()){

                dbresult= rs.getString(3);
            }

     }catch (SQLException e) {

      e.printStackTrace();
     }    

  return dbresult;

}
```

The Access table is composed of three columns:
UserID, UserName, UserPassword

Comment: doesn't the title answer the question?

Comment: Debug and check if query is actually returning any value. i.e `if(rs.next())` is true.

Comment: @davida. a. As I mentioned, the code is right because I tried it in another program just copying and pasting, and I did not have this problem. The database always grants the access to the root user.

Comment: @Aniket Thakur yes it does

Comment: Try to print userName and password right before the getConnection() call and check if they're really correct.

Comment: the debug stops at con = DriverManager.getConnection(DatabaseURL, userName, password);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

As you have mentioned problem is with creating connection with the database itself. Statement

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection(DatabaseURL, userName, password);
```

is throwing exception which is getting caught at

```
catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

after which you are returning `dbresult` which you have initialized to `null`(which you have to as it is a local variable). So the problem is that you are unable to connect to your db due to authentication.

On your machine where (localhost in ur case ) run the following command from console

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: I love you, however, I have not got why it worked with my previous code without granting access